# What plugin should I use to add Microformats to my blog

Tags: plugins

What plugin should I use to add Microformats to my blog?

So that information about author, ratings and comments are picked up by the search engines?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what theme you use - default *WordPress* themes like *TwentyTen* render standard *Microformat* content as per what you require. Look around for a suitable theme.